# How do I return an element from a bash array using a partial string match?

Tags: bash, string, array

I have a bash array containing several elements, only one of which will be in the format nn.wr , where nn is a variable integer.

eg

```
array=( "abcd" "01.wr" "ef_gh" )
```

However it could be anywhere in the array. How can I find it and return it?
I was trying to use the partial match *.wr but can't quite get sed or awk to do it.

There must be a way!!

Answer (score 4):

No need for external commands like `sed` or `awk`. Loop over the elements and use pattern matching:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
array=( "abcd" "01.wr" "ef_gh" )
unset found
for e in "${array[@]}" ; do
    if [[ $e == +([0-9]).wr ]] ; then
        found=$e
        break
    fi
done

[[ $found ]] && echo "$found"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could switch to `zsh` which has builtin operators for that:

```
array=( "abcd" "01.wr" "ef_gh" xx.wr 99.wr )
```

- first

  ```
  $ print -rC1 -- $array[(r)[0-9][0-9].wr]
  01.wr
  ```
- last

  ```
  $ print -rC1 -- $array[(R)[0-9][0-9].wr]
  99.wr
  ```
- index of first¹:

  ```
  $ print $array[(i)[0-9][0-9].wr]
  2
  ```
- index of last²:

  ```
  $ print $array[(I)[0-9][0-9].wr]
  5
  ```
- all

  ```
  $ print -rC1 -- ${(M)array:#[0-9][0-9].wr}
  01.wr
  99.wr
  ```

---

<sup>¹ If not found, that returns one more than the index of the last elememnt</sup>

<sup>² If not found, that returns 0</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Provided your components don't contain a newline you can do something like this

```
array=( "abcd" "01.wr" "ef_gh" )
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+\.wr$'
```

Result

```
01.wr
```

If they do contain newlines you may be able to use `grep`'s non-standard extensions

```
array=( "abcd" "01.wr" $'44.zz\n9.p' "ef_gh" )
printf "%s\0" "${array[@]}" | grep -Exz '[[:digit:]]+\.wr'
```

Result

```
01.wr
```

For a short array it would be more efficient to [loop across it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676343/100397). For a large array using an external operator such as `grep` may well be faster.